# Stopping hang into left margin with enumitem

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

I'm trying to use `enumitem` to present various numbered principles, and to keep a running count on these principles.  I'm getting stuck because I can't get enumerate not to shift the label into the left margin, except by forcing a very large margin for the whole principle.

I'm hoping for something betweeen the two (not working) examples below, where  - where the label doesn't hang into the left margin, but the text is allowed to wrap so it isn't so heavily indented.  Do you have any suggestions?  Many thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.

\begin{enumerate}[label=\small\textsc{Longlabel}-\arabic*\normalsize,labelindent=7em,itemindent=2em]
  \item   elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere eni ultricies.  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.
  \item  mi vel lacus dictum iaculis. Aenean vestibulum    pharetra magna, sit amet    venenatis velit posuere ut. dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.
\end{enumerate}

 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim ltricies.

\begin{enumerate}[label=\small\textsc{Longlabel}-\arabic*\normalsize,leftmargin=7.2em]
  \item   elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.
  \item  mi vel lacus dictum iaculis. Aenean vestibulum   pharetra magna, sit amet venenatis velit posuere ut. dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing   elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim.
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Lockstep's fix works pretty near perfectly for enumerate environment. Is there a way of replicating it when I use itemize to refer back to a previous example?

Minimal example below shoes problem with hanging indent again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.

\begin{enumerate}[label=\small\textsc{Longlabel}-  \arabic*\normalsize,labelindent=*,itemindent=*]
  \item\label{test2}   elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere eni ultricies.  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}[labelindent=*,itemindent=*]
\item[\ref{test2}]elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere eni ultricies.  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `leftmargin=*,itemindent=*`. (If that's close to, but not exactly what you want, try setting `itemindent` to, say, 4em.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.

\begin{enumerate}[label=\small\textsc{Longlabel}-\arabic*\normalsize,leftmargin=*,itemindent=*]
  \item   elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.
  \item  mi vel lacus dictum iaculis. Aenean vestibulum   pharetra magna, sit amet venenatis velit posuere ut. dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing   elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Wth regard to your follow-up question: Replacing the normal `itemize` item with a cross-reference to an `enumerate` item is somewhat unusual, but the option `align=left` produces the desired alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.

\begin{enumerate}[label=\small\textsc{Longlabel}-  \arabic*\normalsize,labelindent=*,itemindent=*]
  \item\label{test2}   elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere eni ultricies.  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}[labelindent=*,itemindent=*,align=left]
\item[\ref{test2}]elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere eni ultricies.  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.
\item   elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere eni ultricies.  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim    ultricies.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really good what you've done, but the problem is I can't replicate it on my computer. I try running your minimal example and get error message  "Missing number, treated as zero <to be read again> *  ... leftmargin=*,itemindent=*]

Comment: @user25244 You probably have an outdated version of `enumitem` -- v3 included major new features. Try to update your TeX distribution.

Comment: I've now updated my version of enumitem and this works fine for the  minimal example,  text, even when I make the label much longer.  But in my own document there's still sometimes a tiny over hang when the theorem number goes into two digits.  But it's a tiny overhang, and with only 2 days before thesis submission, I think this is a good-enough fix. Many thanks!

Comment: @user25244 You're welcome -- and don't forget to upvote (as soon as you have 15 rep) and accept my answer. ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I've now edited to add a further query about itemize lists. Sorry about this!

Comment: Unusual I know - but I have to remind the reader occasionally between chapters about what principle I'm talking about, and this works well. And your fix, again, works beautifully. So again, I'm really grateful for your help.  Thank you!

Comment: Also, adding align=left to the original suggestion of [labelindent=*,itemindent=*], to make [labelindent=*,itemindent=*,align=left] also fixes the slight overhang for theorem numbers greater than 9.