# How do I correctly align normal enumerate and enumitem items?

Tags: lists, enumerate, indentation, enumitem

I have a mixed list of normal and enumitem numbered items. It is working perfectly apart from my inability to create the correct left hand margin and hanging indent for the enumitem. I've tried numerous methods and cannot get any change to the indentation. I don't get any errors or warnings, just nothing happens at typesetting. It is my dissertation, so is a long document and I would prefer not to add anything special to the document set-up for what is likely to be a one-off case.

The numbering is working correctly, the inline numbers are working correctly, it's just the indent that's wrong. It's a normal paragraph indentation, not an indented list item.

I've [read the manual](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), I've also [looked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369544/how-do-i-get-a-custom-enumeration) [at](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282854/how-do-i-understand-the-horizontal-spacing-of-enumitems-enumerate-list) [various](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291604/how-do-i-indent-a-line-in-an-enumeration-environment) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96017/stopping-hang-into-left-margin-with-enumitem) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195290/align-itemize-bullet-to-text) [but](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490872/enumitem-understanding-the-usage-of-asterisk-and-exclamation-mark-in-setting-th) I still can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

A toy example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
        bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
        head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}    
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem} 

\begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Duis at tellus at urna. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget:
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat.
 \item Purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris.
 \item Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla. 
 \item Duis convallis convallis tellus id.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate*}[start=5]
\item Fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum, 
\item pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis.
\end{enumerate*}
\begin{enumerate} \addtocounter{enumi}{6}
\item Neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget. 
\end{enumerate}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you want to obtain is not very clear. Could you explain more in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
        bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
        head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Duis at tellus at urna. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget:
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat.
 \item Purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris.
 \item Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla.
 \item Duis convallis convallis tellus id.

\item Fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum, \begin{enumerate*}[label =\arabic*., start=6]
\item pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis.
\end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate} \addtocounter{enumi}{6}
\item Neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That 5 kept starting like it was part of a paragraph. I didn't realise I could nest them in each other. Four hours of frustration solved just like that! It's working perfectly.